# PHP Map infinite object

Tags: php, laravel

I have some struggles with how to map infinite objects in PHP.
I have objects like:

```
    {
        "id": "2",
        "parent_id": "1",
        "children_recursive": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "parent_id": "2",
                "children_recursive": [
                    {
                        "id": "5",
                        "parent_id": "3",
                        "children_recursive": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "parent_id": "2",
                "children_recursive": []
            }
        ]
    }
```

And from this, I would need to get all id values in one single array.
I don't think that for each is the best approach here, what would you do?

EDIT: This question is changed!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($get_categories as cat) {
    cat->'column name' // Extract column name
}
```

Hope this info is sufficient enough.

Comment: Thanks, I changed a question btw. Fixed with database problem